# Is it possible that HttpServerUtility.MapPath locks the file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, concurrency, locking

Two functions in our standard ASP.NET app are:

```
        private static void SaveToFileSystem(AttributeFileAttachment attach, int paId)
    {
        string fileName = GetAttachmentFullName(attach.FileName, paId);
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, attach.Content);
    }

    public static string GetAttachmentFullName(string name, int paId)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = Util.Util.GetHttpContext();
        return string.Format("{0}{1}_{2}_{3}",
            ctx.Server.MapPath("<some variable to get the path>" + "attributeFileAttachments\\"),
            ctx.Session.SessionID,
            paId,
            name);
    }
```

when File.WriteAllBytes is executed it returns exception:

*he process cannot access the file '\\d$\Home\\attributeFileAttachments\' because it is being used by another process.*

The essence are two lines:
ctx.Server.MapPath... (Microsoft code)
and File.WriteAllBytes...
that work on the same file.

It turns out that HttpServerUtility.MapPath locks the file and leaves it locked !?
I don't see any comments on that in official documentation nor I see anybody complains on that.

But it can't be anything else, since the two lines are consecutive.
When I modify fileName for File.WriteAllBytes in immediate window just a bit, the writing succeeds, since that new file is not locked.

One more thing I have noticed is that this happens only and always for some of the attachment files.

Thank you for the time and any advice.

Comment: Look again at your code - what you're suggesting can't be correct because you're using the string *returned* from `MapPath` inside of a larger `string.Format` - the file name returned by your `GetAttachmentFullName` is not the same as either the input to `MapPath`, nor to any file name that it, itself, generates.

Comment: Is there an option that the whole directory from MapPath stays locked? How is it possible that there are any concurrency issues when the two lines are consecutive and are executed for the same request? The path for file reported to be locked is constructed only in GetAttachmentFullName method, so how can it be locked by anything else but something in that function? I don't see anything but MapPath being a candidate? Thank you

Comment: Are there any other functions that also consume `GetAttachmentFullName()` and that might have been called earlier during the same request? Or even on an earlier request? So far as I'm aware, `MapPath` doesn't touch the file system at all - it just performs string manipulation. So even if the file is locked, `MapPath` should always succeed - you need to identify something that happened even earlier that does actually touch the file system.

Comment: To troubleshoot the issue, you can download and run Process Monitor (from Sysinternals), filtering by the name of the file, and look for access violations in the trace.